# Как определить, является ли число палиндромом?

Tags: c#

Как с помощью строк можно проверять числа на палиндром, это числа читаемые с обеих сторон одинаково
121, 55455 и т.д

Comment: В чем проблема то? также, как и строку, можно проверить

Comment: перевести в строку, одну - реверснуть и сравнить. Или проверять в цикле

Answer (score 7):

В функциональном стиле:

```
var s = "12321";
if (s.Reverse().SequenceEqual(s)) Console.WriteLine("Палиндром!");
```

Классическое императивное решение (будет немного быстрее работать):

```
static bool IsPalindrome(string s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length / 2; ++i)
        if (s[i] != s[s.Length - 1 - i]) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Если на входе число - предварительно получите его строковое представление:

```
var v = 12321;
var s = v.ToString();
```

Comment: Только Studio открыл, а Вы уже ответ дали!)

Comment: @EgorRandomize, кто успел — тот и съел!

Comment: классическое решение, я бы сказал будет работать в 2 раза быстрее. При общей сложности O(N): проверка `SequenceEqual` отработает ровно за N, против N/2 в классике.

Comment: @rdorn: Плюс не забывайте расходы на разворот/копирование, которые сравнимы с расходами на сравнение.

Comment: @VladD я посмотрел, при правильном подходе, Reverse вернет IEnumerable, а значит ни какого копирования и расходов, хотя накладные от LINQ все равно ни куда не денутся. В простейшем случае да, + доп память,+копирование

Comment: @rdorn, `Reverse` должен вычитать последовательность до конца и закешировать ее, думаю, исходники не смотрел

Comment: @АндрейNOP Посмотрел исходники, да - кэширует, и пускает обратный итератор по кэшу. Хотя конкретно для строк можно было и не кэшировать, они же неизменяемы. Ну тогда все еще хуже, не в 2, а в 3 раза классика быстрее =) а это уже не "немного" Если только руками реверс-итератор написать. [пруф](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,e247ee4147678571)

Comment: @rdorn, можно было бы проверять, реализует ли входной параметр `IList` и просто выдавать элементы из него в обратном порядке, но со строками всё равно досада – они не реализуют `IList`, у них индексатор только геттер имеет, в отличие от `IList`

Comment: поэтому для строк придется отдельную проверку делать...

Comment: Можно в Linq-решение понатыкать `Take(s.Length / 2)`, но красота кода будет утеряна и тогда уже лучше будет предпочесть императивное решение