# Как разделить строку на слова игнорируя любые символы кроме букв?

Tags: c#

Вот есть задача https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-palindrome/

Я понимаю, что строку нужно сначала рассплитить, избавиться от всевозможных знаков, склеить в одну строку и эту строку сравнить со своим перевертышем.

Я понимаю, что вот так:

```
string s = "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama";
string[] array = s.Split(new char[] {' ', ':', ','});
foreach(var ch in array)
    Console.WriteLine(ch);
```

это неправильно, потому что я фактически захардкодил двоеточие, пробел и запятую. если мы введем любую другую строку с другими знаками - работать корректно не будет.

Предложите, пожалуйста, варианты решения.

Comment: Идите от обратного – берите только значащие символы, например: `var symbols = s.ToLower().Where(c => c >= 'a' && c <= 'z').ToList();` ну и потом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/783192/218063

Comment: Вот так у меня прошло все тесты: `var symbols = s.ToLower().Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант без Linq и без лишних выделений памяти.

```
public bool IsPalindrome(string s)
{   
    for (int i = 0, j = s.Length - 1; i < j;)
    {
        var ci = s[i];
        var cj = s[j];
        if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(ci) && char.IsLetterOrDigit(cj))
        {
            var loweri = char.ToLower(ci);
            var lowerj = char.ToLower(cj);              
            if (loweri!=lowerj) return false;
            i++;
            j--;
            continue;
        }

        if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(ci)) i++;
        if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(cj)) j--;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

LINQ вариант:

```
public bool IsPalindrome(string s)
{
    var resStr = s.Where(Char.IsLetterOrDigit).Select(Char.ToLower);
    return resStr.SequenceEqual(resStr.Reverse());
}
```

Comment: аааа, что за треш? Изначальная задача — проверить является ли строка палиндромом

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну в вопросе пишется про разбиение на слова.

Comment: @АндрейNOP "Как разделить строку на слова игнорируя любые символы кроме букв?" Собственно, вот слова мы и получили.

Comment: Не, у автора [Ошибка XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/218063), вы же ему даете рекомендации по тому как держать микроскоп при забивании гвоздей, вместо того чтобы посоветовать взять молоток

Comment: @АндрейNOP ок, поправил.

Comment: `considering only alphanumeric characters`

Comment: @tym32167, ок, поправил.

Comment: Ну и если сигнатура метода совпадает с делегатом параметра, лямбду писать не нужно

Comment: @АндрейNOP ок, сейчас должно быть идеально.

Comment: :) Мой плюсик уже стоит

Answer (score 2):

Нужно идти от обратного

В памяти, буквы английского алфавита расположены по порядку друг за другом (большие и маленькие отдельно), поэтому если наш символ подходит под описание буквы, то мы его выводим

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama";
        foreach (var ch in s)
        {
            if((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'))
                Console.WriteLine(ch);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```